# my android game works very well on unity editor but not on device

Tags: unity, unityscript, debugging

Im working on a android unity project. My game works very well on the editor but, when i build it and run it on blue stacks emulator, it starts working corruptly. Bullets shoot twice in a time. When level is not started, the screen to the next level shows and...  what can be the cause of this problem?  maybe reason is bad emulator

Comment: BlueStacks is like, the worst option for a simulator. There are tons of other options that are free and run better

Comment: @DH. can you give me some examples? im downloading handy andy

Comment: That's a better option. There's Memu too, http://www.memuplay.com

Comment: I'm using Nox, it works better than device ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueStacks is just a simulator. Use a real device for testing. Problem is not the build or Unity.

I tried running APK on BlueStacks. It had UI, Shadow etc issues but runs fine on devices.

Comment: ok. thank you so much for your help. i will try to run it on a real device but i play many android games on blue stacks.

Comment: I could too. But had issues sometimes.
I couldn't even run Assassin's Creed Identity properly. Also some of my games.